# What does it mean a line in bash manual, "Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words."

Tags: bash

I am reading [bash manual on "Expansion"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html),
It said it has 7 type of expansion/substitution including "word splitting".
On the other hand, it said at the head of the item:

> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words.

I could not understand what is "split into words". In other words, I could not understand the difference between "split into words" and "word splitting counted as expansion".

Please let me know what "Expansion  is  performed  on  the command line after it has been split into words." means.

Does it mean, assuming

```
$> var1="word splitting"
$> var2="single_word"
$> command var1 var2
```

"Expansion  is  performed  on  the command line after it has been split into words." -> parsing words

```
word1 = command
word2 = var1
word3 = var2
```

"word splitting" -> assigning positional parameter by delimiter

```
$1 = "word"
$2 = "splitting"
$3 = "single_word"
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you fedorqui for editing question above. If you don't mind could you tell me how to make the yellow cell, "Expansion ~~~" or please let me know the site of format/rule and editing facility of stack overflow you follow. Thank you.

Comment: See [Markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also, if you want to mention someone you need to add `@` before his/her name. So I saw this comment because I entered the question again, but to be notified you should've said `@fedorqui ...`.

Comment: @fedoqui thank you for giving me instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the manual for bash states this:

> Expansion is performed on the command line after it has been split into words.

It means that the command line starts as one whole string, then, from left to right, that string is split on metacharacters:

> metacharacter
>      A character that, when unquoted, separates words. One of the following:
>                |  & ; ( ) < > space tab

What results from such splitting is called "words" or "tokens".

That is applied to the whole command line string.

---

In contrast, what is called "word splitting" is applied only to the result of "unquoted expansions" and use only the characters in `$IFS` to split.

Thus, this command line prints only two lines:

```
$ a="word splitting"  b="single_word"

$ printf '%s\n' "$a" "$b"
word splitting
single_word
```

The command line: `printf '%s\n' "$a" "$b"` was divided by spaces into four tokens (words):

one: `printf`, two: `'%s\n'` three:`"$a"` and four:`"$b"`.

If the same command line is unquoted:

```
$ printf '%s\n' $a $b
word
splitting
single_word
```

Then, the third token (word): `word splitting` is subject to word splitting and becomes two token (words): `word` and `splitting` (because IFS contains an space by default).

The fourth token is also subject to word splitting (as it is unquoted) but remains as one token (word) as it has no IFS characters.

Please note that "word splitting" is usually associated with globing in that both are applied to unquoted expansions. Globing could be turned off by the command `set -f` and word-splitting could be avoided by using quoting.

Comment: word splitting and "globbing" (pathname expansion) are two separate processes. What's important is that word-splitting happens first, so that the expansion of `*`, for example, is the list of filenames in the current directory, not the list of words in the filenames. While they are usually either both enabled or both disabled in any given context,  you can global disable pathname expansion with `set -f`; that has no effect on word-splitting.

Answer (score 1):

There are people out here with a better understanding of bash than me, but I'll give it a try.

As you cite it, the manual describes that before anything else is done, the command is split into words. **Edit:** As rici (thanks) pointed out, the parsing rules for the command line are different from the word splitting after the expansions. Among other differences, the IFS variable is not consulted but instead words are simply delimited by blanks or special characters (blanks are tab or space). See the comments below for an example.

Then all other expansions are performed. Then,

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, and arithmetic expansion [...] for word splitting.

Essentially, it treats the results of the other expansions as a new command line, with a few exceptions.

```
$> command $var1 $var2
```

(note that you must prefix the variable names with a dollar sign when used) becomes, due to parameter expansion:

```
command word splitting single_word
```

(one string, letters and spaces). This string (the whole line) is split into the obvious words again. The first word is usually interpreted as a command, the others become the command's positional parameters. `command` would see 
$1 as *word*, $2 as *splitting*, and $3 as *single_word*.

Thus, word splitting is performed twice, in different ways: Once on the original command line, respecting quotes and other special constructs; and once on the result of the other expansions, using the IFS variable, ignoring quotes etc. bash does not recursively perform the other expansions on that result, by the way (that is, if a positional parameter as the result of the expansion is a string like "$var1", it is taken literally, as if passing it in single quotes).

Comment: Thank you very much. If you saw my previous comment, please don't mind. My opinion did not have much meaning. Thank you again

Comment: The command is not parsed into words using `IFS`. The precise parsing algorithm is specified in the standard and documented in shell manuals. It recognises quoting characters and also self-delimiting characters such as `;` and `)`.  Word-splitting (which is strictly based on `IFS`) is totally different. It is important to not confuse these two very different operations.

Comment: @rici Thanks. Is the following an example for what you mean?  I just tried: `a=\"ls\ -l\"; echo $a; $a` which results in `"ls -l"`, next line: `-bash: "ls: command not found`. As opposed to simply `"ls -l"`, resulting in `-bash: ls -l: command not found`. The difference is that  it's the whole command when `"ls -l"` is given directly on the command line, because the initial command parsing respects quotes, while the result of the expansion of `$a` is simply split into words at spaces, ignoring quotes, so that the first word is just `"ls`.

Comment: @Charles I thought the distinction between syntactic and literal quotes is one of the differences between the two word splitting procedures... Anyway, I'd appreciate it if you (or rici, anybody) corrected any remaining errors or misleading information in my answer, if you find time. As I said, I'm not a bash wiz and always happy to learn myself.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, ahh. I was considering quote removal to be a separate phase from parsing into words. It *is* documented that way, but at the same time, that's arguably a not-particularly-useful level of hairsplitting. Withdrawing my comment above.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: When you write `echo $a` (or, for that matter, `$a`), the shell substitutes `$a` with the value in the variable `a` (parameter substitution) *and then word-splits*. If you had written `echo "$a"`, then `a` would have been substituted, but no word-splitting would be performed. Because of the way echo works and the fact that there is only a single space in the value, those two operations are not distinguishable. However, `$a` and `"$a"` will produce different error messages and you should examine them closely to see the difference (first trying to predict it would be good).

Comment: A good idiom to see how arguments are word-split is to use `printf ++%s++\\n ` instead of `echo`. `printf` repeats the format as often as needed until the arguments are used up, so that will print each argument on its own line surround with `++` (so you can see newlines and trailing spaces more easily).